# Setting arbitrary properties in Fluent NHibernate configuration

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I've got a Fluent NHibernate project where I need to set a few arbitrary properties on the NHibernate configuration.  My first try was like this, where I start from `Fluently.Configure()`, do some fluent configurin' and call `BuildConfiguration()`, then set some properties on that configuration, and finally build a `ISessionFactory` from it.

```
public static class NHibernateConfigurator
{
    private static readonly Configuration _configuration;
    private static readonly ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

    static NHibernateConfigurator()
    {
        _configuration = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(SQLiteConfiguration
                .Standard
                .InMemory()
                .Provider<TestConnectionProvider>()
                .FormatSql())
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<AcademicTermMapping>())
            .BuildConfiguration();

        _configuration
            .SetProperty(Environment.CollectionTypeFactoryClass, typeof(Net4CollectionTypeFactory).AssemblyQualifiedName)
            .SetProperty(Environment.CurrentSessionContextClass, "thread_static");

        var props = _configuration.Properties;
        if (props.ContainsKey(Environment.ConnectionStringName))
            props.Remove(Environment.ConnectionStringName);

        _sessionFactory = _configuration.BuildSessionFactory();

    }
```

While I do end up with a working session factory, the `.SetProperty` calls in the middle seem to get ignored. (In particular, I know the `Environment.CollectionTypeFactoryClass` is ignored, because of the exception I get.  I'm assuming the rest of it is also ignored.)

The next try uses `ExposeConfiguration()` to have a crack at setting properties:

```
    static NHibernateConfigurator()
    {

        _configuration = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(SQLiteConfiguration
                .Standard
                .InMemory()
                .Provider<TestConnectionProvider>()
                .FormatSql())
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<AcademicTermMapping>())
            .ExposeConfiguration(ConfigModifier)
            .BuildConfiguration();

        _sessionFactory = _configuration.BuildSessionFactory();

    }

    private static void ConfigModifier(Configuration config)
    {
        config.SetProperty(Environment.CollectionTypeFactoryClass, typeof(Net4CollectionTypeFactory).AssemblyQualifiedName);
        config.SetProperty(Environment.CurrentSessionContextClass, "thread_static");

        var props = config.Properties;
        if (props.ContainsKey(Environment.ConnectionStringName))
            props.Remove(Environment.ConnectionStringName);

    }
```

But that doesn't seem to work, either.  Fortunately, one of the properties has a corresponding fluent method, so I can do this:

```
_configuration = Fluently.Configure()
    .CollectionTypeFactory<Net4CollectionTypeFactory>()
    // ... etc...
```

But there's no fluent equivalent for the rest of it.  I feel like I must be doing this wrong.

**Update**

Now it's getting weird.  Following @Firo's advice, I checked the configuration properties after the `BuildConfiguration()`.  Either setting the property manually with `.SetProperty` on the configuration, or using the fluent `.CollectionTypeFactory<Net4CollectionTypeFactory>()` sets the same property on the config.  But they end up in a different order.  So I tried setting the property manually on a new config, then continuing from there:

```
    static NHibernateConfigurator()
    {
        var baseConfig = new Configuration();
        baseConfig.SetProperty(Environment.CollectionTypeFactoryClass, typeof(Net4CollectionTypeFactory).AssemblyQualifiedName);

        _configuration = Fluently.Configure(baseConfig)
            .Database(SQLiteConfiguration
                .Standard
                .InMemory()
                .Provider<TestConnectionProvider>()
                .FormatSql())
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<AcademicTermMapping>())
            .ExposeConfiguration(ConfigModifier)
            .BuildConfiguration();

        _sessionFactory = _configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    private static void ConfigModifier(Configuration config)
    {
        config.SetProperty(Environment.CurrentSessionContextClass, "thread_static");

        var props = config.Properties;
        if (props.ContainsKey(Environment.ConnectionStringName))
            props.Remove(Environment.ConnectionStringName);
    }
```

And that works.  The different methods produce all the same properties, just in a different order.  The above produces these in `_configuration.Properties`:

```
[0] = {[use_reflection_optimizer, True]}
[1] = {[collectiontype.factory_class, DataAccess.NHibernate.Net4CollectionTypeFactory, DataAccess.NHibernate, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]}
[2] = {[connection.provider, DataAccess.NHibernate.Tests.TestConnectionProvider, DataAccess.NHibernate.Tests, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]}
[3] = {[connection.driver_class, NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver, NHibernate, Version=3.3.1.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4]}
[4] = {[dialect, NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect, NHibernate, Version=3.3.1.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4]}
[5] = {[hibernate.dialect, NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect, NHibernate, Version=3.3.1.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4]}
[6] = {[query.substitutions, true=1;false=0]}
[7] = {[connection.release_mode, on_close]}
[8] = {[format_sql, true]}
[9] = {[connection.connection_string, Data Source=:memory:;Version=3;New=True;]}
[10] = {[current_session_context_class, thread_static]}
```

The other methods move the `collectiontype.factory_class` around in the order, but the order shouldn't matter.

Comment: can you confirm that `.CollectionTypeFactory` sets `config.Properties.ContainsKey(Environment.CollectionTypeFactoryClass)`

Comment: @Firo: I updated the question after investigating this.

Comment: Awesome question with builtin answer! `ConfigModifier` fixed my customized requirement! Your question is appreciable.